# Calculating Foreign Key Totals in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-tables2

I am wanting to make tables to show total scores for both user and teams.

Models:

```
class Team(Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Player(Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    player_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    player_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Game(Model):
    score = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    game_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GAME_CHOICES)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each Game relates to a specific player and a specific team. Each player can be in multiple teams so no relation there.

In my table I am wanting totals for the score by each player and the score for each team.

The code I have tried for my table:

```
class PlayerTable(tables.Table):
    sum_scores = tables.Column(Player.objects.annotate(total_score=models.Sum('game__score')))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        exclude = ["id"]
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-sm'}
```

However, this does not seem to work.
How do I resolve this so that the last column in the player table will be each players total score?

Comment: why do you want to create a table column? I think it will be better if you generate a dummy field of sum during orm query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Player record you can use the custom data render function to gather the data.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods

```
class PlayerTable(tables.Table):
    sum_scores = tables.Column()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        exclude = ["id"]
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-sm'}

    def render_sum_scores(self, record, value):
        player_games_qs = record.game_set.all()
        return sum([score for score in player_games_qs.values_list("score")])
```